# Issue while using Jboss eap 5.1

Tags: java, apache, maven, jboss

I am facing an issue in JBoss EAP 5.1 .It works fine on jBoss 5.1.0 GA but gives an error in JBoss EAP. I found the same issue posted on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284565/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-poi-poixml?newreg=830b44bc1d1c439bb89955b5d3996a32),
I tried the solutions suggested there but still it is not working.
I also found that there is a jar called stax-api in JBoss 5.1.0 GA and that the concerned class is somehow dependent on it. stax-api is not there in jBoss eap5.1 so I placed it there, It still doesn't work . Can anyone help??
it gives the following error on executing

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument
```

Comment: jar is missing. add Apache POI - poi-ooxml-3.6. search for relevant jar.

Comment: I can't believe that if it works on JBoss 5.1 that it is a vanilla installation; You probably have a manually changed JBoss 5.1 installation where the jar was added, which is a bad idea as you have now proven. Deploy the jar with the application and it will work anywhere.

Comment: I have already tried it but it is still not working. poi-ooxml-3.6 has been added already but its is somehow not able to get the class. I suspect some jar is missing on which poi-ooxml is dependent, I even checked for the but couldn't find what is missing.